# Salesforce Data Cloud (CDP) Data Retention Policy

Tags: datacloud, salesforce-cdp

I'm new to Salesforce Data Cloud (CDP). Are there options to set data retention policies on data streams? (e.g. delete records older than X days)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of now there is data retention like in SFMC you can follow below link where you can remove records from Individual by following the process.

https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.c360_a_delete_data_stream_records_deletion_file.htm&type=5